# How to modify setup page?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to add some information on wpSelectComponents page about components/types of the installation.

Is there a possibility to add some text / description to for example wpSelectComponents page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want static text, you can set custom text using the `[Messages]` section (See Inno's `Default.isl` for the current values and names).

If you want to show more descriptive text when selecting a component, you will need to do it in `[Code]` by creating your own labels on the page and setting the text as appropriate.